# ROS Fuerte and PCL from source on ARM / Hard-float support

Tags: pcl, external-libraries, ros-fuerte, pandaboard, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Unfortunately, I can't use the apt-get install ros-fuerte-pcl command and need an installation from source. (I'm using an ARM board and Ubuntu 12.04)
I'm asking because it seems that in the new ROS Fuerte setup the PCL Library is not included and is seen as an external system dependency.

When i use $roslocate info pcl I get the following output:

- svn:
  local-name: pcl
  uri: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl

But this website doesn't exist.
But there seems to be a special PCL version for ROS (see the Willow Garage repository [https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl-release] ) saw that at answers.ros.org ([link](http://answers.ros.org/question/37472/compiling-pcl_trunkvisualization/))

So i tried to compile the code from WG with the USE_ROS option on ON and it fails to compile with the following failure.

```
[  1%] Built target gtest 
[  1%] Built target gtest_main 
[  8%] Built target pcl_common 
[  9%] Built target pcl_kdtree 
[ 10%] Built target pcl_octree 
[ 12%] Built target pcl_search 
[ 23%] Built target pcl_sample_consensus 
[ 23%] Built target pcl_geometry 
[ 26%] Built target pcl_segmentation 
[ 26%] Building CXX object io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io_ply.dir/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp.o 
In file included from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply.h:45:0, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h:61, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp:41: 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/byte_order.h:65:4: error: #error 
In file included from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply.h:45:0, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h:61, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp:41: 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/byte_order.h:77:4: error: #error 
In file included from /home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp:41:0: 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h: In member function ‘bool pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::parse_scalar_property(pcl::io::ply::format_type, std::istream&, const typename pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::scalar_property_callback_type<ScalarType>::type&)’: 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h:577:51: error: ‘host_byte_order’ was not declared in this scope 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h: In member function ‘bool pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::parse_list_property(pcl::io::ply::format_type, std::istream&, const typename pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::list_property_begin_callback_type<SizeType, ScalarType>::type&, const typename pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::list_property_element_callback_type<SizeType, ScalarType>::type&, const typename pcl::io::ply::ply_parser::list_property_end_callback_type<SizeType, ScalarType>::type&)’: 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h:648:51: error: ‘host_byte_order’ was not declared in this scope 
/home/panda/ros/pcl-release/io/include/pcl/io/ply/ply_parser.h:674:53: error: ‘host_byte_order’ was not declared in this scope 
make[2]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io_ply.dir/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io_ply.dir/all] Error 2 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Would be great to get your thoughts about that issue. Thanks
What should be the normal way to install pcl for ROS Fuerte when its not possible to use debian-pkgs?

I asked this question in the [pcl-users forum](http://www.pcl-users.org/ROS-Fuerte-and-PCL-from-source-failure-to-build-ply-parser-h-error-host-byte-order-was-not-declared--td4021813.html) as well

---

### Edit:

As I was expecting it, it was something with the hardfloat support of ubuntu 12.04 for the Armel architecture because the ply_parser tries to compare the host_byte_order with the endian_byte_order at this point. So Jochen from PCL changed alot in the trunk version to get that working.

Therefore, I downloaded the trunk ( r7013 / which uses Boost to detect the byte order)  and compiled everything without a failure. I just got several of these ROS related warnings:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:57:0, 
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:34, 
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:43, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/tools/icp2d.cpp:41: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h: In member function ‘double ros::DurationBase<T>::toSec() const’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h:93:41: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h:93:60: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h: In member function ‘int64_t ros::DurationBase<T>::toNSec() const’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h:94:43: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/duration.h:94:71: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:34:0, 
                 from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:43, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/tools/icp2d.cpp:41: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h: In member function ‘double ros::TimeBase<T, D>::toSec() const’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:152:44: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:152:63: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h: In member function ‘T& ros::TimeBase<T, D>::fromSec(double)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:153:51: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:153:103: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h: In member function ‘uint64_t ros::TimeBase<T, D>::toNSec() const’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:155:47: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:155:77: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:47:0, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:43, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/tools/icp2d.cpp:41: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<bool>::write(Stream&, bool)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:210:26: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<bool>::read(Stream&, bool&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:217:15: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ContainerAllocator> >::write(Stream&, const StringType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:238:27: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:242:39: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ContainerAllocator> >::read(Stream&, ros::serialization::Serializer<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ContainerAllocator> >::StringType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:253:49: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::Serializer<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ContainerAllocator> >::serializedLength(const StringType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:263:35: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::disable_if<ros::message_traits::IsFixedSize<T> >::type>::write(Stream&, const VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:339:34: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> >::type>::write(Stream&, const VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:389:37: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:393:57: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> >::type>::read(Stream&, ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> >::type>::VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:407:51: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> >::type>::serializedLength(const VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:414:45: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:47:0, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:43, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/tools/icp2d.cpp:41: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::and_<ros::message_traits::IsFixedSize<T>, boost::mpl::not_<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> > > >::type>::write(Stream&, const VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:431:34: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function ‘static uint32_t ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<T, ContainerAllocator, typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::and_<ros::message_traits::IsFixedSize<T>, boost::mpl::not_<ros::message_traits::IsSimple<T> > > >::type>::serializedLength(const VecType&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:460:43: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In member function ‘uint32_t ros::serialization::Stream::getLength()’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:686:63: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In function ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeMessage(const M&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:809:38: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:810:28: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h: In function ‘ros::SerializedMessage ros::serialization::serializeServiceResponse(bool, const M&)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:831:40: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:832:27: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:833:30: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:842:40: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/serialization.h:843:27: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:49:0, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:43, 
                 from /home/panda/ros/pcl/tools/icp2d.cpp:41: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<signed char>::stream(Stream&, const string&, int8_t)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h:56:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<unsigned char>::stream(Stream&, const string&, uint8_t)’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h:66:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: At global scope: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: In instantiation of ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<M>::stream(Stream&, const string&, const M&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, M = unsigned int, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:239:5:   instantiated from ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator> >::stream(Stream&, const string&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’ 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:102:1:   instantiated from ‘std::ostream& std_msgs::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’ 
/home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/PointIndices.h:32:20:   instantiated from here 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h:42:15: warning: unused parameter ‘indent’ [-Wunused-parameter] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: In instantiation of ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<M>::stream(Stream&, const string&, const M&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, M = ros::Time, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:241:5:   instantiated from ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator> >::stream(Stream&, const string&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’ 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:102:1:   instantiated from ‘std::ostream& std_msgs::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’ 
/home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/PointIndices.h:32:20:   instantiated from here 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h:42:15: warning: unused parameter ‘indent’ [-Wunused-parameter] 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h: In instantiation of ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<M>::stream(Stream&, const string&, const M&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, M = std::basic_string<char>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’: 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:243:5:   instantiated from ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator> >::stream(Stream&, const string&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with Stream = std::basic_ostream<char>, ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’ 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs/Header.h:102:1:   instantiated from ‘std::ostream& std_msgs::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std_msgs::Header_<ContainerAllocator>&) [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’ 
/home/panda/ros/pcl/common/include/pcl/PointIndices.h:32:20:   instantiated from here 
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_operations.h:42:15: warning: unused parameter ‘indent’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

- finally I tried to compile openni_launch which leeds me to the following failure message about the **depth_image_proc** can't find pcl ( [rospack] Error: package/stack depth_image_proc depends on non-existent package pcl ). But **openni_launch** apperently find's the installed pcl ( In file included from /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/common/io.h:46 )
- here is the full failure message:

  ```
    mkdir -p bin 
    cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  .. 
    [rosbuild] Building package depth_image_proc 
    Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests depth_image_proc 
    [rospack] Error: package/stack depth_image_proc depends on non-existent package pcl 

    CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message): 


    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 
    'depth_image_proc'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting. 
    Please fix the broken dependency! 

    Call Stack (most recent call first): 
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack) 
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init) 


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} 
    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package depth_image_proc written to: 
    [ rosmake ]    /home/panda/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120830-090256/depth_image_proc/build_output.log 
    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< depth_image_proc [FAIL] [ 5.41 seconds ] 
    [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package depth_image_proc. 
    [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. 
    [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesl_ros: 51.3 sec ]           [ 1 Active 42/48 Complete ] 
    {------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
      Finding dependencies for /home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/cfg/EuclideanClusterExtraction.cfg 
      -- Configuring done 
      -- Generating done 
      CMake Warning: 
        Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: 

      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE 


      -- Build files have been written to: /home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build 
      cd build && make -l2 
      make[1]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[2]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      [ 36%] Built target ROSBUILD_gencfg_cpp 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      [ 36%] Built target rospack_gencfg 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      [ 36%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      [ 36%] Built target rosbuild_precompile 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_tf.dir/src/pcl_ros/transforms.o 
      In file included from /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/common/io.h:46:0, 
                       from /home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/transforms.cpp:38: 
      /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/pcl_base.h:54:30: fatal error: pcl/PointIndices.h: No such file or directory 
      compilation terminated. 
      make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_tf.dir/src/pcl_ros/transforms.o] Error 1 
      make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_tf.dir/all] Error 2 
      make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
      make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 
      make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl_ros/build' 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} 
    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl_ros written to: 
    [ rosmake ]    /home/panda/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120830-090256/pcl_ros/build_output.log 
    [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros [FAIL] [ 51.37 seconds ] 
    [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl_ros. 
    [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. 
    [ rosmake ] Results: 
    [ rosmake ] Built 44 packages with 2 failures. 
    [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory 
    [ rosmake ] /home/panda/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120830-090256
  ```

Would be great to get the new pcl integrated into ROS Fuerte... So please help

### EDIT 2:

I used $rosmake pcl17 which took 5 hours to compile and I was really full of hope that this attemp will work. But after trying $rosmake openni_launch produces the same failure I posted before (post from Aug 30, 2012; 9:19am).

Now, I figured out what the problem/missunderstanding is. The pcl17 is a package to use the current trunk in the ROS environment beside an existing pcl installation (I think at the moment its version 1.5). But its still not a standalone version which is playing nicely with ROS, right?

I try to explain it again:
I just want to use openni_launch package (which needs pcl) on my pandaboard (armel). Because of the armel architecture I need to compile everything from source and I can't use $sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl so I tried to use $roslocate info perception-pcl (which is normaly pointing to the source code of the needed package, in this case http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable) but this site is still not existing. And actually no need for me too use the unstable version its just what ROS is telling me (even the official website is pointing to the unstable version [link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl)) so I was trying to find a version which will work with ROS. And then I tried to ask here....

I'm totally confused and I would really much appreciate if someone could explain me when I did something wrong or when my way of thinking is wrong...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37216/ros-fuerte-and-pcl-from-source-on-arm-/-hard-float-support/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-25**:
Is this ROS Fuerte or Electric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PCL-developers did a great job over the weekend and pushed things further . Its now possible to use pcl 1.7 beside an existing pcl installation for ROS respectively as working pcl source for an ARM-board (Thumps up)

To use this 1.7 trunk version as source for your ROS there are some tricks to do. ( My objective was it to run openni_launch -> which depends on depth_image_proc -> which needs pcl )

Here's what you need to do:

1. `$ svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable/`
2. `$ roscd pcl17_ros && make`
3. check out https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_pipeline/trunk/depth_image_proc/ (URL taken from here:
   http://ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc), add it to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in front of all the rest.
4. go to depth_image_proc and apply the patch (which is basically changing includes and namespaces from pcl to pcl17) attached to this post and make, i.e.:

```
$ roscd depth_image_proc 
$ patch -p0 < pcl17_trunk.patch 
$ make
```

I hope I saved someones time :)

### patch:

Because I can't upload a patch file. Just copy this into a new createt file named pcl17_trunk.patch

```
Index: manifest.xml
===================================================================
--- manifest.xml    (revision 40052)
+++ manifest.xml    (working copy)
@@ -24,8 +24,8 @@
   <depend package="image_transport"/>
   <depend package="message_filters"/>
   <depend package="nodelet"/>
-  <depend package="pcl"/>
-  <depend package="pcl_ros"/>
+  <depend package="pcl17"/>
+  <depend package="pcl17_ros"/>
   <depend package="roscpp"/>
   <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
   <depend package="stereo_msgs"/>
Index: src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp
===================================================================
--- src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp    (revision 40052)
+++ src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp    (working copy)
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
 #include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
-#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
-#include <pcl/point_types.h>
+#include <pcl17_ros/point_cloud.h>
+#include <pcl17/point_types.h>
 #include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
 #include <image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h>
 #include <boost/thread.hpp>
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@
 
   // Publications
   boost::mutex connect_mutex_;
-  typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
+  typedef pcl17::PointCloud<pcl17::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
   ros::Publisher pub_point_cloud_;
 
   image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model_;
@@ -119,7 +119,7 @@
   {
     for (int u = 0; u < (int)cloud_msg->width; ++u)
     {
-      pcl::PointXYZ& pt = *pt_iter++;
+      pcl17::PointXYZ& pt = *pt_iter++;
       T depth = depth_row[u];
 
       // Missing points denoted by NaNs
Index: src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyzrgb.cpp
===================================================================
--- src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyzrgb.cpp (revision 40052)
+++ src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyzrgb.cpp (working copy)
@@ -5,8 +5,8 @@
 #include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
 #include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
 #include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
-#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
-#include <pcl/point_types.h>
+#include <pcl17_ros/point_cloud.h>
+#include <pcl17/point_types.h>
 #include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
 #include <image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h>
 #include "depth_traits.h"
@@ -45,7 +45,7 @@
 
   // Publications
   boost::mutex connect_mutex_;
-  typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> PointCloud;
+  typedef pcl17::PointCloud<pcl17::PointXYZRGB> PointCloud;
   ros::Publisher pub_point_cloud_;
 
   image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model_;
@@ -243,7 +243,7 @@
   {
     for (int u = 0; u < (int)cloud_msg->width; ++u, rgb += color_step)
     {
-      pcl::PointXYZRGB& pt = *pt_iter++;
+      pcl17::PointXYZRGB& pt = *pt_iter++;
       T depth = depth_row[u];
 
       // Check for invalid measurements
```

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-04**:
Be aware that this patch only fixes `depth_image_proc`. You will need to make similar changes to every other package you build that uses `pcl`.